# Handler in loop

Tags: android, for-loop, handler

I have to update different server data which takes huge time. I have to update the data on conditions. When I am running for loop, it's stuck the device for a minute. I want to do through handler else any other option (which I can't think). currently I am doing as:

```
for(int i=0;i>10;i++)
{
if(i==0)
handler.post(runable-1);//Different server data
if(i==1)
handler.post(runable-2);//different server data
if(i==2)
handler.post(runable-3);//different server data
...
}
```

How could I do? Also I have to show to user that which runnable is loading data...
Please help. Thanks

Comment: are you sure about your for loop?

`for(int i=0;i>10;i++)`...is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is `AsyncTask`.  In your Activity class add

```
class UpdateServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Object obj = null;
    private ProgressDialog dlg;

    @Override
    protected voide onPreExecute() {
        dlg = ProgressDialog.show (MyActivity.this, "", "Please wait, updating server...", true, false);     
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            switch(i) {
                case 0: ...;
                        break;
                case 1: ...;
                        break;
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        dlg.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And then, when you need to do the update:

```
new UpdateServerTask().execute(null);
```

Read up more on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also, note that your `for` loop is not correct it should be `<10` and not `>10`.  Finally, I suggest you use `switch` case instead of `if-else if-else` construct.

Answer (score 0):

You should actualize these server data using a Service instead of posting tasks on activity. Make a custom Service for this and you will have your activity free to do anything.